# "У млекопитающего" или "у млекопитающих"? Что стилистически верно?

Tags: переводы, множественное-число, число

> Настоящее изобретение касается терапевтического лечения антагонистами, которые связываются с поверхностными В-клеточными маркерами. В частности, изобретение касается применения таких антагонистов для лечения аутоиммунных заболеваний **у млекопитающего**, у которого наблюдается неадекватный ответ на ингибитор ФНО.

В оригинальном английском тексте имеется в виду "любое млекопитающее, у которого использование ингибитора ФНО не дало эффекта".

Можно ли в русском языке использовать (как в английском) "млекопитающего" в единственном числе, или единственно верным вариантом будет переход в множественное число?

> Настоящее изобретение касается терапевтического лечения антагонистами, которые связываются с поверхностными В-клеточными маркерами. В частности, изобретение касается применения таких антагонистов для лечения аутоиммунных заболеваний **у млекопитающих**, у которых наблюдается неадекватный ответ на ингибитор ФНО.

Допустимо ли первое, хоть и смотрится хуже стилистически?

Что-то в нём меня коробит...

Comment: Вас не затруднит этот кусочек дать по-английски?  Там в оригинале *mammal*  -  с артиклем стоит? И который - witch или that? К сожалению, не помню деталей, но когда разбирались с этим, была какая-то рекомендация. Вроде бы так. *Если **any thing, witch**, то множественное при переводе просто недопустимо. А если ***something that**, то лучше именно множественным.* Но это по жуткому склерозу, ногами не бейте.

Comment: И еще. В сочетании *"**у** млекопитающего, **у** которого"* первый предлог лишний по стилистическим соображениям. Думаю, патентную строгость это не нарушит, если его убрать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В патентные текстах (в формулах изобретения и не только) важен не столько изящный стиль, сколько однозначность излагаемого. Из варианта с множественным числом здесь не вполне ясно, идёт ли речь о видах млекопитающих, для которых всегда наблюдается отрицательная реакция, или об отдельных особях неназванного вида (какое ни возьми млекопитающее), проявивших такую реакцию. Если бы так было написано в юридически значимой части текста (в формуле), то потенциально возможны были бы даже разногласия по поводу неоплаченного использования изобретения (например: "*а у нас в каждом случае было одно млекопитающ**ее**, а не млекопитающ**ие***" - платить не обязаны). Поэтому не исключено, что первый вариант предпочтителен - грамматической ошибки в нём нет.

Comment: Спасибо, Алекс! Попробую почитать про особенности патентных переводов.